# How to move sys_note display from footer to top in TYPO3 list view?

Tags: javascript, php, typo3, typo3-8.x

The TYPO3 sysext `sys_notes` is using `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['recordlist/Modules/Recordlist/index.php']['drawFooterHook']` to render the content of notes at the bottom of the list module.

I'd like to display the notes on top of the list module, right after the flash messages. Unfortunately there is no hook to do so. Is there any other alternative? Maybe I can inject some JavaScript to move the content to top, but I don't know how. Any ideas where to look for a solution?

Comment: I know that there is an open issue about that https://forge.typo3.org/issues/61170

Comment: I've added my +1 to the idea, but that doesn't solve my problem ;)

Comment: So let's just add a hook? https://review.typo3.org/#/c/55423/ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core patch from Georg Ringer works fine for me.

Note: this patch will not be integrated in TYPO3 8.7 due to the feature freeze.

If you want to use it with TYPO3 8.7, you can xclass the core or patch it if you use Composer:

1. `composer require cweagans/composer-patches`
2. download the diff from [Gerrit](https://review.typo3.org/changes/55423/revisions/80047d68ebf19944613682d320e3089c34be5fd2/patch?zip)
3. put the patch file to build/patches or a similar location
4. add this to the `"extra"` section of your `composer.json`:

   ```
   "patches": {
       "typo3/cms": {
           "Hook for sys_notes #61170": "build/patches/80047d6.diff"
       }
   }
   ```
5. `composer update typo3/cms`
6. last but not least, use the new hook in your `ext_localconf.php`:

   ```
   // reset hook from sys_note to render notes at the bottom of the list module
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['recordlist/Modules/Recordlist/index.php']['drawFooterHook']['sys_note'] = '';

   // render sys_note notes in the header instead
   $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['recordlist/Modules/Recordlist/index.php']['drawHeaderHook']['sys_note'] = \TYPO3\CMS\SysNote\Hook\RecordListHook::class . '->render';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround: Add a flash message with a information about sys_notes and a link (anchor) to the bottom.

Comment: not possible as a flash message can't contain any HTML ;)